# How to make a generic map using template in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, arguments

I am trying to create a generic `map` which will take`any datatype` as its 2nd elelment.
But when I am trying create an object I am getting error as `argument list for class template is missing`

```
template<typename T1>
class MAP{
public:
    std::map<string, T1>Hello;

    //MAP(){Hello["Hello"] = 3;}
};

int main()
{
    MAP map1;//Error happens here

    return 0;
}
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: `MAP` is not a type. `MAP<int>` is. `MAP<char>` is. `MAP<double>` is. `MAP<MAP>` is.

Comment: If you want a single map object able to store elements of several different types at the same time, you want to stop and think again. What would you do with such a map? How would you operate on its elements? Otherwise you already have a generic map, it's called `std::map`.

Comment: @chris `MAP<MAP>` is NOT a type, it's an error. `MAP<MAP<int>>` is a type.

Comment: @Angew, Woops, thanks for correcting me. I was originally going to say `MAP<YourOwnClass>` and then I switched it to `MAP` since it was already defined and I guess I forgot that meant I needed an extra template argument :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your code sample, not on the description of the problem, it looks like what you are trying to implement can be expressed with an alias template:

```
template <typename V>
using MAP = std::map<std::string, V>;
```

This requires C++11 support. But an instance of `MAP` can only have one mapped type `V`, as in your code sample.

```
MAP<int> mi;    // std::map<std::string, int>
MAP<double> md; // std::map<std::string, double>
```

If you want to store any type as mapped type, you could consider using a map of [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/any.html)

```
using ANYMAP = std::map<std::string, boost::any>;

ANYMAP m;
m["Hello"] = 42;
m["Bye"] = std::string("message");
```

but then you have to think carefully about how to use this construction.